# Implementing sockets into $http in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, sockets, http

I implemented Primus (Sockets) on my Server and would like to access it via the client, which uses AngularJS. I would like to be able to still use libraries like Restangular or the $resource from Angular. So IMHO the best way to achieve this is to extend the $http service, which is used by most libraries as the basis.

I would like this new service to be able to gracefully fall back to the normal $http, when there is no socket connection available.

In Pseudocode:

```
socketHttpService = function(config) {
    if(socketEnabled) {
        var message = buildMessageFromConfig();
        primus.write(message);
        return promise;
    }
    return $http(config);
}
```

Call it like you would $http

```
socketHttpService({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).then(function() {
    // do whatever
});
```

My question is, how can i replace the standard $http service with this newly created one? Is there an elegant way, while still retaining the default $http behaviour?

In the meantime, I found a solution to the problem

```
.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$httpBackend', function($delegate, $q, $log, SocketService) {

        // do not blast mock $httpBackend if it exists
        if (angular.isDefined(angular.mock)) {
            return $delegate;
        }

        var httpBackendSocket = function(method, url, post, callback, headers, timeout, withCredentials, responseType) {
            if(SocketService.isOpen) {
                console.log('open');
                method = method.toLowerCase();
                // we only know get, post, put, delete
                if(method === 'get' || method === 'post' || method === 'put' || method === 'delete') {
                    // we can not handle the authentication links via sockets, so exclude them
                    if( url.substring( 0, '/api/v1/currentuser'.length ) !== '/api/v1/currentuser' &&
                        !angular.equals(url, '/api/v1/login') &&
                        !angular.equals(url, '/api/v1/logout') &&
                        !angular.equals(url, '/api/v1/session') ) {

                        var promise = SocketService.writeRest(method, url, post || {});
                        return promise.then(function promiseSuccess(response) {
                            return callback(response.status, response.data, response.headers, '');
                        }, function promiseError(response) {
                            // is caught via http handlers
                            // LATER: If error, retry with $httpBackend ($delegate)
                            return callback(response.status, response.data, response.headers, '');
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            return $delegate(method, url, post, callback, headers, timeout, withCredentials, responseType);
        }

        return httpBackendSocket;
    });
})
```

Why? Because it feels like 5 times faster than http, because there is a standing connection and I am not losing any of the realtime options. It's like a cherry on top.

Kind Regards

Comment: It's certianly possible, but I have to ask - why? Sockets and HTTP messages are inherently different. HTTP is stateless and is built for structured responses representing a resource or a document. Sockets are meant for more real time data. I don't think treating them the same is a very nice abstraction in the general case.